# Can we send custom data as ancillary data in socket programming?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

I am learning socket programming in c/c++ and came across cmsghdr and msghdr. I am trying to pass custom struct as ancillary data in the unix domain socket which I created. My question is whether we can send custom struct or other type of data and if yes, what should be the options (type, level etc) I should select ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No. Ancillary data is only for specific kinds of data for each socket type. To send your own data, just send it normally with `send`.